Does legislation in India allow electronic communication devices to be in stand-by when driving?
Jurisdiction: Union of India
Legislation/s: Central Motor Vehicles Act, Motor Vehicles Rules

Quote
Section 184 of the Motor Vehicles Act: States that whoever drives a
motor vehicle in any public place while using a handheld mobile phone
or any other electronic device shall be punishable with a fine of
₹1,000 to ₹5,000 and/or imprisonment for a term of up to 6 months.
Rule 21(25) of the Central Motor Vehicles Rules: Prohibits the use of
mobile phones or any other electronic device while driving, except for
hands-free modes like Bluetooth or wireless headsets.
Unquote

The keyword, to me - a layman, appears to be the word "use". It is commonplace to see drivers having the mobile phone on a stand and following map directions on it.
If a device such as a mobile phone is powered on, does it fulfill the criteria of being "in use"? What if a person is listening to music, or radio instead?

As best as I can make out, the intent may have been to reduce distraction to a minimum. Whilst a person may not actively use their hand/s to listen, it is not at all uncommon to use their hands for any purposes. Hands may not be the auditory channel per se. Yet adjusting the volume on a radio, or keying a microphone, or changing the radio channel all probably qualify.Similar activities may be performed  using a mobile phone as a map.


The keyword, to me - a layman, appears to be the word "use". It is commonplace to see drivers having the mobile phone on a stand and following map directions on it.

Besides the key word "use" the regulation also uses the key words "hands free mode". These key words are probably more significant than "use" as they pertain to the intent of the regulation. i.e. It really doesn't matter whether you are listening to music or looking at a map, the point is to not use your hands.
Placing the mobile phone on a stand as you have observed drivers doing is a way to use the device while keeping your hands free to maintain control of the vehicle.

If a device such as a mobile phone is powered on, does it fulfill the criteria of being "in use"? What if a person is listening to music, or radio instead?

Yes, using the mobile device to stream music fulfills the criteria of being "in use".  However, as explained above as long as the device is in some sort of holder so that the driver is using it in "hands free mode" then this is permissible.
P.S. The title references a "stand-by mode" that this answer does not address because it isn't clear what that means.  However, it would seem that the device mode would be irrelevant, with "hands free" being the defining element of determining compliance.
